# ionic node Error: Path must be a string. Received { [String:

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

i have problem when try to build ionic app 
this error

```
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode
```

i think the problem was the node version ,so i install the latest version

when i try to run : ionic build android

```
Error: Path must be a string. Received { [String:
 'C:\\PROGRAM FILES\\NODEJS\\NO
DE.EXE']
  stdout: 'C:\\PROGRAM FILES\\NODEJS\\NODE.EXE',
  stderr: null,
  code: 0,
  cat: [Function: bound ],
  exec: [Function: bound ],
  grep: [Function: bound ],
  head: [Function: bound ],
  sed: [Function: bound ],
  sort: [Function: bound ],
  tail: [Function: bound ],
  to: [Function: bound ],
  toEnd: [Function: bound ],
  uniq: [Function: bound ] }
```

---

and when i try to run : cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist

```
Error: Path must be a string. Received { [String: 'D:\\PHONE GAP\\PROJECTS\\RENT
CLUB\\PLATFORMS\\ANDROID\\CORDOVA\\VERSION.BAT']
  stdout: 'D:\\PHONE GAP\\PROJECTS\\RENTCLUB\\PLATFORMS\\ANDROID\\CORDOVA\\VERSI
ON.BAT',
  stderr: null,
  code: 0,
  cat: [Function: bound ],
  exec: [Function: bound ],
  grep: [Function: bound ],
  head: [Function: bound ],
  sed: [Function: bound ],
  sort: [Function: bound ],
  tail: [Function: bound ],
  to: [Function: bound ],
  toEnd: [Function: bound ],
  uniq: [Function: bound ] }
```

---

any ideas ?
and thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to re install all the things from node [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), git [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads), cordova and ionic.

you can check node version by command `npm -v` and git version by `git --version`

For Cordova : `npm install -g cordova`

For Ionic : `npm install -g ionic`

Create app : `ionic start appName blank`

Goto app folder : `cd appName`

Add platform : `ionic platform add android`

Build your project : `ionic build android`

I hope it will work for you.